# Serial communication between windows and linux displaying junk characters

Tags: .net-core, serial-port

I am developing a program for serial port communication between windows and linux system. When i send message from linux to windows i get junk characters and not the actual message, same happens when i send message from windows to linux. My code for data received event is:

```
void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        _serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

       Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
}
```

I am only getting junk characters on both windows and linux. Same code is running on both machines. What am i doing wrong ? is there some encoding issue ? My code is is .NET Core 3.1. Configurations are:

Baud Rate : 2400

Parity : none

Databits : 8

HankShake : none

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure both sides have identical speeds configured? Please share serial port initialization code.

Comment: yes, i am using same configurations. I have edited the question and added the configurations in the question @MaximSagaydachny